# Can you pass TypeORM driver-level parameters or provide TypeORM a pre-created connection/pool?

Tags: node.js, typeorm, mysql2

I'm using TypeORM v0.2.31 in a Node.js application with the `mysql2` driver. The `mysql2` driver supports many custom parameters such as connection compression via the `compress: true` parameter, of which I would like to leverage in my application (I'll stick with compression for this example since it's easy to prove). When I test compression directly with a `mysql2` connection it works. But when I do this via TypeORM `createConnection()` the parameter does not get passed to the underlying driver. Here's an example of testing both raw `mysql2` and TypeORM:

```js
    // Test 1: MySQL2
    const conn2 = mysql2.createConnection({
        user: "my_user",
        password: "my_pass",
        database: "my_db",
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3306,
        compress: true // WORKING
    });

    conn2.query('SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE "Compression"', function(err, res) {
        console.log('COMPRESS TEST 1: ', res); // TRUE|ON
    });


    // Test 2: TypeORM
    const conn = await createConnection({
        "type": "mysql",
        "host": "localhost",
        "port": 3306,
        "username": "my_user",
        "password": "my_pass",
        "database": "my_db",
        "compress": true // NOT WORKING
     } as any);


    const comp = await conn.query('SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE "Compression"');
    console.log('COMPRESS TEST 2: ', comp); // FALSE|OFF
```

Can I pass driver-level parameters through TypeORM or at least pre-configure a database connection (or pool) from `mysql2` and then pass it to TypeORM? The `compress: true` is just one example which is why it's important we figure out how flexible TypeORM really is.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [typeorm documentation](https://typeorm.io/#/connection-options/common-connection-options) you need to pass the driver options in the `extra` property. I assume this should work:

```
const conn = await createConnection({
  // ...
  "database": "my_db",
  "extra": {
    "compress": true
  }
} as any);
```